# How do I add a click event to multiple elements and detect on the most detailed node?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a web application - The front end has in each table cell so to speak, a span tag with text and a select tag with about 25 options that are going to eventually be drawn from the server.  The select tag is hidden(display: none) until the span tag text is clicked.  That's all good but when the seelct tag is visible, I want to add a click handler on something (pretty much everything else that will (if the most intimate/detailed tag clicked is not the currently edited id) blur the current select and restore display to the span for that element/table cell-ish section.  This is what I have now:

```
$("body")
            .click(function()
            {
                if(getCurrentEditingId() != null)
                    {
                    var cbo = $("#cbo" + getCurrentEditingId());

                    if((typeof($(this).attr("id")) != "undefined") && ($(this).attr("id").length > 0))
                        if($(this).attr("class") == "UsherLabel")
                            {
                            var sId = $(this).attr("id").substr(3);

                            if(sId != getCurrentEditingId())
                                cbo.blur();
                            }
                        else
                            cbo.blur();
                    else
                        cbo.blur();
            });
```

The problem is - when I click on the first entry (nothing had been clicked yet), it goes through the click handler about 15 times - from least relevant to most relevant (body, table, tbody, tr, td, ..., span).  How do I get it to JUST to the most relevant - so if I click on a span, it won't execute click() on a body or table or tr tag prior to getting to the span tag click.  I also don't just want to put it on span's though - because what if someone DOES click on empty space in a table row or even just the body itself or a button that is in the table footer to submit changes?  All of those should also reset the visibility of the span tag that was hidden previously.  I know I can put element.data("clicked") to see if it's clicked but I have a feeling that it would return true for body and everything general as well as the most specific thing clicked.

Do I have to maybe do some logic testing the children of the tag being processed for data("clicked")?  and if one returns true, then ignore this click handler instance?  I was hoping there would be a way to specialize the semantics of to what I was attaching a click handler.  Thanks!

Edit: (As requested in a comment)

This is just a clipping as it is part of a larger 'expression':

```
$("<span></span>",  {   "class":    "UsherLabel"
                                                                        ,   id:         "lbl" + dtDate.getFullYear() + ("0" + parseInt(dtDate.getMonth() + 1)).split(-2) + ("0" + dtDate.getDate()).split(-2) + "S" + (iServiceLoop + 1) + "U" + objUsherService.getNumber()
                                                                        })
                                                        .click(function()
                                                        {
                                                            var sId = $(this).attr("id").substr(3);

                                                            if(getCurrentEditingId() != null)
                                                                $("#cbo" + getCurrentEditingId()).blur();

                                                            for(var iLength = $("#cbo" + sId + " option").length, iLoop = 0; iLoop < iLength; iLoop++)
                                                                {
                                                                var objOption = $($("#cbo" + sId + " option")[iLoop]);

                                                                if(objOption.html() == $(this).html())
                                                                    {
                                                                    $("#cbo" + sId).val(objOption.val());

                                                                    break;
                                                                    }
                                                                }

                                                            $(this).hide();
                                                            $("#cbo" + sId).show();

                                                            setCurrentEditingId(sId);
                                                        })
                                                        .html(objConsistory.getName())
```

Edit 2:  I resolved the issue - I just check the target of the event and don't go on the tag on which I set the event handler

Comment: Can you show us the click handler for the span that shows the select ?

Comment: As I put in my edit just now, I resolved the issue.  I check the event.target that is passed to the click handler and based on that target's id I can do my logic then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to stop propagation?

Something like:

```
$('.clickTarget').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do other stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I resolved the issue anyhow - I pass to the click handler event as a parameter and inside the method, check event.target and use that object's 'id' to determine if I want to act on it or not.

Comment: @SethD.Fulmer sounds complicated, you can register click event to document and dictate what is `e.target` by conditions (if/else if/else)

Comment: It's actually quite simple - If the target's id is NOT what I've set as the currently editing Id, then blur the currently editing control - which puts the label/span back into visibility.  Probably only simpler in angular but I didn't want to use angular in this project.